# PowerShell v2 Adding a Printer

Tags: powershell, printing, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to create a PowerShell Script that allows me to add and configure a printer with 3 instances of the printer. This is what I have so far:

```
# Printer Info
$printerID = "HP Designjet Z3200 24in Photo"
$printerID1 = "HP Designjet Z3200 24in Photo - Canvas"
$printerID2 = "HP Designjet Z3200 24in Photo - Cover"
$printerIP = Read-Host 'What is the Poster Printer IP Address?'
$printerPort = "IP_$printerIP"
$printerModel = "HP Designjet Z3200 24in Photo"
# Speak with Ted about a specific place to put the poster driver pre-extracted
$driverINFPath = "C:\Velocity\HP WFP\Driver\hpdjz3200serieswx64pcl\hpi32pxs.inf"

# Build a new Local TCP Printer Port, naming it with values unique to the Printer ID:
$newPort = ([wmiclass]"Win32_TcpIpPrinterPort").CreateInstance()
$newPort.HostAddress = $printerIP
$newPort.Name = $printerPort
$newPort.Put()

# Add the printer
printui.exe /if /b "$printerID" /f "$driverINFPath" /u /r "$printerPort" /m "$printerModel"
printui.exe /if /b "$printerID1" /f "$driverINFPath" /u /r "$printerPort" /m "$printerModel"
printui.exe /if /b "$printerID2" /f "$driverINFPath" /u /r "$printerPort" /m "$printerModel"
```

I copied the part from an earlier post for the port part of the script. I'm trying to figure out what the .Put() is and I cannot find it anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I've given a reference for `Put()` below - *but* if you're having a problem with this method (which I suspect) please clarify here in the comments and [edit] your question so I can edit my answer to help you with your issue.

Comment: @gravity I actually found what I needed right before seeing this comment. Thanks for the comment and answer!

Comment: I suspect you needed to wrap all of the assignment in a function, yes?  :)

Comment: That would be correct. @gravity Lets hope it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ...Windows PowerShell accesses WMI through the .NET Framework and
>   System.Management class. Rather than using SWbemObject, Windows
>   PowerShell uses the System.Management.ManagementObject class. For
>   better or worse, **this class uses a method named Put to save changes to
>   a read-write property**.

From [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692805.aspx), which actually is comparing VBScript `Put_` to PowerShell `Put()` calls.